# MVC Telerik DropDownList Setting First item OnLoad

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, telerik-mvc

I have a MVC Telerik DropDown List. I am getting the Data through Ajax Binding. On the Page Load I want the First SelectList Item to be Autopopulated. What is the best way of achieving this.

After Googling and educating how Telerik AjaxBinding works. I came to a conclusion that Ajax binding will activate the call only when the Dropdown is Clicked.

Best way of achieving my requirement?

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

You could force the DropDownList to fetch its data when the page is loaded via the fill method

```
$('#ComboID').data().tComboBox.fill()
```

Or add that one value initially on the server side via the **Items** method.